# Inflating Exception when inflating view in Service while it's inflating normally in activity

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, service, android-inflate

When trying to inflate  `View` like this:

```
val lay: LayoutInflater = getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as (LayoutInflater)
mView = lay.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_order, null)
```

I see a inflating exception:

> Binary XML file line #0: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1:
>   TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f030006 a=-1}

But when write the same lines in activity it's working normally !

View XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:drawableStart="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:drawablePadding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/new_order"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/order_image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_rest_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_xlarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_customer_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_btns_border"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/order_price"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/order_pay_method"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:gravity="center" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/gray_lite" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:padding="10dp"

            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/order_delivery_time"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0 Min"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="@string/to_restaurant" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/order_accept_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_btns_rounded_green"
        android:text="@string/order_status_start_pickup"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Service is an activity without a UI. What are you trying to accomplish here? What are you expecting to do with the layout you want to inflate from a Service?

Answer (score 1):

as per say's Alessio  that is right Service has no `UI` so you can't use `inflater` on it if you want to show view on Activity from your service then pass your `Activity Context` and Show `View`

```
LayoutInflater lay=(LayoutInflater)Context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)

mView = lay.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_order, null)
```